# How to login using more than one string in Asp.net..?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web

```
string email = "value1 & value2";
string password = "pass & pass1";
if (TextBox1.Text == email & TextBox2.Text == password)
{
    Session["id"] = TextBox1.Text;
    Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
    Session.RemoveAll(); 
}
else
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Sorry !! Email Id Or Password wrong ')", true);
}
```

How to perform or operation in string email and password

Comment: Are you asking just to use more than 1 combination of username/password or how to have a database of users who can login?

Comment: Unclear what your question is, you also have a syntax error on your if statement. You need `&&`.

Comment: Are your strings seperated by " & " ?

Comment: Use `&&` instead `&`. See: `if (TextBox1.Text == email && TextBox2.Text == password)`.